# Python string comparison performance is inconsistent

Tags: python, string, time, char, compare

I wanted to check how string comparison works (I wanted to see if it is char by char, and if it checks the length of the string before the comparison), so I've used this code:

```
s1 = 'abc'
s2 = 'abcd'
s3 = 'dbc'
s4 = 'abd'
t1 = time.clock()
s1==s2
print time.clock() - t1
t2 = time.clock()
s1==s3
print time.clock() - t2
t3 = time.clock()
s1==s4
print time.clock() - t3
```

When I've tried the same thing on very long strings (~30MB text files) it worked great and I found out that it does perform a length check, and also it compares char by char.
But when I've tried it on short string (such as the string in the code above) the performance results were very inconsistent.
Any one has any idea why they were inconsistent or what have I done wrong? (perhaps I was wrong and the comparison doesn't work as I thought?)

Edit: An example for something I've also tried is to compare different lengths of string with a specific string. I thought that the one that takes the longest to perform will be the string with the exact length of the other one because the rest will fall in the length check, but it was inconsistent as well).
lets say that the string I'm checking is 'hello', so I've compared 'a', 'aa', 'aaa', and so on...
I was expecting to see that the longest check will be 'aaaaa' but it was 'a' and I have no idea why.

Comment: "the results were very inconsistent" - in what way? What output did you expect, and what did you see?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I've just edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: `time.clock` isn't a great choice for benchmarking the speed of Python code, especially in modern multitasking OSes where potentially dozens of other processes can be hogging the CPU for fractions of a second while your script executes in fits and bursts. `timeit` would be better, since it can average out periods of heavy load, but there's still some inherent imprecision.

Comment: 90% of your post makes it sound like the equality tests themselves are producing inconsistent results. I suggest editing it to make it clear that you're talking about the _performance_. That said, testing a single comparison of only a few characters is bound to have inconsistent performance results. That's why most tests run many times.

Comment: Assuming you're using the CPython implementation of the language, you can read how string comparison is performed [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a985b6455fde/Objects/stringobject.c#l1192) (in C).

Comment: You may want to look at how Python stores strings internally. The short version is that many short strings are stored (at compile time) as pointers if they are the same as an existing string. There are caveats to this that may explain the inconsistency you saw. Here is some interesting reading for you: http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/

Comment: Your program isn't being run in isolation.  There are many other processes that run interspersed with your python code.  Look into things like Big O notation to learn how to classify algorithm speeds.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.
So is there still a way to check what I'm trying to accomplish? (for example what I've said in the post about the length check I tried to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that strings compare lengths before comparing contents (at least in 2.7). [Here](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Objects/stringobject.c#l1214) is the relevant portion of `string_richcompare`:

```
if (op == Py_EQ) {
    /* Supporting Py_NE here as well does not save
       much time, since Py_NE is rarely used.  */
    if (Py_SIZE(a) == Py_SIZE(b)
        && (a->ob_sval[0] == b->ob_sval[0]
        && memcmp(a->ob_sval, b->ob_sval, Py_SIZE(a)) == 0)) {
        result = Py_True;
    } else {
        result = Py_False;
    }
    goto out;
}
```

In simple terms, the checks appear to be, in order:

- if the strings have the same memory address, they are equal. (not pictured in the above code)
- if the strings have a different size, they are not equal.
- if the strings have a different first character, they are not equal.
- if the strings have identical character arrays, they are equal.

The third check doesn't appear to be strictly necessary, but is probably an optimization if manually checking array contents is faster than calling `memcmp`.

---

If your benchmarking suggested to you that comparing strings of different length is slower than comparing strings of the same length, this is probably a false alarm caused by the not entirely dependable behavior of `clock`, as covered in other answers and comments.

Comment: Thank you when combining both of your answer I managed to perform a check that is working as expected. Thank you both very much!

Answer (score 2):

You are liable to get inconsistent results when measuring very small times.
You'll get better result by repeating the operation a great many times so that the difference is substantial:

```
t1 = time.clock()
for i in range(10**6):
    s1 == s2
t2 = time.clock()
```

Better yet, use the timeit module to handle the repetition (and other details
like turning off garbage collection) for you:

```
import timeit

s1 = 'abc'
s2 = 'abcd'
s3 = 'dbc'
s4 = 'abd'
t1 = timeit.timeit('s1==s2', 'from __main__ import s1, s2', number=10**8)
t2 = timeit.timeit('s1==s3', 'from __main__ import s1, s3', number=10**8)
t3 = timeit.timeit('s1==s4', 'from __main__ import s1, s4', number=10**8)
for t in (t1, t2, t3):
    print(t)
```

yields

```
2.82305312157
2.83096408844
3.15551590919
```

Thus `s1==s2` and `s1==s3` take essentially the same amount of time. `s1==s4` requires a bit more time because more characters have to be compared before the equality can return False.

---

By the way, while `time.clock` is used by `timeit.default_timer` for measuring
time on Windows, `time.time` is used by `timeit.default_timer` for measuring
time on Unix. Use `timeit.default_timer` instead of `time.clock` or `time.time`
to make your code more cross-platform compatible.

Comment: Thank you when combining both of your answer I managed to perform a check that is working as expected. Thank you both very much!